# How to make HTML table that can be resized to the visible window with button (javascript)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table (decided to throw everything from my previous question out and have it draw a plain old table) that needs to be able to be re-sized on the page at the click of a button that calls a javascript function.

The table could be small or it could be huge - far bigger than the page.

I need to have a button that will re-size the table to the **size of the visible window** when clicked. And another button that will put the size of the table back to as big as it was.

This is how the table is made:

```
<table  id=resizableTable cellpadding='5' cellspacing='0' border='0' width: '75%'  leftmargin='50' >
```

How I get the visible window area:

```
var visHeight = window.innerHeight;
var visWidth = window.innerWidth;
```

I tried the following in javascript :

1)

```
document.getElementById('resizableTable').max-width = visWidth + 'px'; 
document.getElementById('resizableTable').max-height = visHeight + 'px';
```

2)

```
document.getElementById('resizableTable').style.width = visWidth + 'px';
document.getElementById('resizableTable').style.height = visHeight + 'px';
```

3)

```
jQuery('#resizableTable').css('width',visWidth + 'px');
jQuery('#resizableTable').css('height',visHeight + 'px');
```

But none of these work -- in fact, the table doesn't change in size at all!  What am I doing wrong?  I haven't even been able to work on the resizing the table back to the original size yet because I've gotten stuck on this part.

Comment: Try this `<table id="resizableTable" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="75%" >` and `$('#resizableTable').css({ width: $(window).innerWidth() + 'px' });` also for height.

Comment: Try `var visWidth = screen.availWidth` & `var visHeight = screen.availHeight` and use valid HTML from my previous comment.

Comment: @mdesdev I tried what you said and the HTML for the table changes to `<table id="resizableTable" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="height: 669px; width: 1905px;">` but the actual table on the screen doesn't change at all... :(

Comment: Ok...I'll make you a fiddle.

Comment: @mdesdev I also inspected the element in chrome console, and when I hover the mouse over (that line) the tooltip box that pops up showing the table information says 1941px x 2518px for the table #resizableTable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a <kbd>**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/25mch/)**</kbd>

```
<button class="on">Full</button>
<button class="off">Normal</button>

<table id="resizableTable">
  <tr>
    <th>Header</th>
    <th>Header</th>
    <th>Header</th>
    <th>Header</th>
    <th>Header</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Data</td>
    <td>Data</td>
    <td>Data</td>
    <td>Data</td>
    <td>Data</td>
  </tr>

  ...more data...

</table>
```

---

```
table {
  width: 70%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}
```

---

```
$(function() {
  $('.on').click(function() {
    $('#resizableTable').css({ 
        width: $(window).innerWidth() + 'px', 
        height: $(window).innerHeight() + 'px'
    });
  });
  $('.off').click(function() {
    $('#resizableTable').css({ 
        width: '70%', 
        height: 'auto'
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: For some reason on the web interface we use it's not letting me set height for the table... your fiddle <table> doesn't have all those settings though -- would they be why? Sorry, I have very little web dev experience.

Comment: You can use `$(document).innerHeight()` instead of `$(window).innerHeight()`. That would give you the height of entire document or set the `height` in `px`. I don't see other options.

Comment: You can add inline height in table tag of course e.g `<table id="resizableTable" width="70%" height="500">`

Answer (score 0):

Set the width and height to percentages. For example:

```
var b = true;
document.getElementById('button').onclick = function() {
    if (b = true) {
    document.getElementById('resizableTable').style.width = '100%';
    document.getElementById('resizableTable').style.height = '100%';
    } else {
    document.getElementById('resizableTable').style.width = '1080px';
    document.getElementById('resizableTable').style.width = '720px';
}}
```

Comment: But how is that going to help with resizing the table so that it fits the visible window?